# JavaFx webview HTML5 drop on Mac

Tags: javascript, javafx

I am trying to use the html5 drag drop in webview browser component. The following is not working on Mac, but works well in windows.

```
droptarget.ondrop = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();
  var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
};
```

data is undefined in MacOS. I can't set the transfer text and the proper mime type because the drag will be initialized from another browser.